# Prove that $|A|\ge |B|$, as $A = \{A_i \vert i \in \mathbb{N}\}, \forall b \in B: b \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that $|A|\ge |B|$, as $A$ and $B$ are two sets described as follows:

$A=\{A_i \vert \ i \in \mathbb{N}\}$, such that $\forall i,j\in\mathbb{N}:i\neq j: \ A_i\neq A_j\land A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$,

$B$ is a set constructed of open intervals on $\mathbb{R}$,

such that for every $b_1, b_2 \in B: b_1 \cap b_2 = \emptyset$,
 $\forall b\in B: \ b = (x,y)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ ($x\neq y$)

> **Prove**: $|A| \ge |B|$, or in other words, Prove there exists a injective function $f: B \to A$.

***My attempt:***

As $B$ is a collection of open disjoint intervals on $\mathbb{R}$, then I'd like to define a partition over $\mathbb{Q}$ using the elements of $B$. Let this partition be called $\pi_{B}$.

By the definition of a partition, then $|\pi_B| = |\mathbb{Q}| =\aleph_0$

This allows me to know that there exists a bijection: $g: \pi_{B} \to A$, and as $\pi_B$ is defined using elements of $B$, then there exists an injective function $h: \pi_{B} \to B$.

I'd like to find a way to define a composition function of $h$ and $g$, such that this composition will be a one to one function: $f: B \to A$, and from that it will be possible to conclude that $|A| \ge |B|$.

But I don't know how to do such thing.

Comment: Your description of the set $A$ has a type error. In your first sentence, you write $A \subset \mathbb N$, so $A$ is a subset of the natural numbers, hence each element of $A$ is a natural number. In your next sentence you write $A = \{A_i \mid i \in \mathbb N\}$, so each $A_i$ is an element of $A$, hence each $A_i$ is a natural number. But later in your second sentence you have the expression $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$; ordinarily it does not make much sense to intersect two natural numbers.

Comment: I think you mean $A\subset P(\mathbb{N})$ and $B\subset P(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @LeeMosher - thankyou

Comment: We do not have $|B|=2^{\aleph_0}$..... $B$ is countable.

Comment: I don't see how it is possible to prove that $B$ is countable

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that $B$ contains no empty intervals.

Note that every interval $b\in B$ contains at least one rational number. This follows as $b$ is open and non-empty, hence we can find at least two elements in $b$, as a singleton set is closed. Since there is always a rational number between every two real numbers we can use the axiom of choice to find a map $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(b)\in b$ for all $b\in B$. Note that this map is unique as the intervals in $B$ are pairwise disjoint. Let $g:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be an injection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Then 
$$h:B\rightarrow A,b\mapsto A_{g(f(b))}$$
is an injection.

To do this without the axiom of choice let $(a,b)$ be an open interval, Let $n$ be the smallest number such that $2^{-n}\leq b-a$. Then the set 
$$X_{(a,b)}=\{z2^{-n}\in (a,b):z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
is non-empty and we can define $f((a,b))=\min X_{(a,b)}$.

Comment: Sidenote, you can do this without the axiom of choice, but it is a bit more work.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to this without AC. Do you have a suggestion on that case?

Comment: I've expanded my answer with a possible explicit definition of $f$.

Comment: Without AC we can define a well-order $<_W$ on $\Bbb Q$ that is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb N$. So  for each non-empty $\beta \in B$ we can let $f(\beta)=\min_{<_W}(\beta\cap \Bbb Q).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet and also without well order theorem otherwise the exception of AC would be irrelevant

Comment: @FlorisClaassens - for the case without AC -  I'm still not sure how do we define a function $g: X \to A$ which will be one to one? I suppose you mean that the function $h = g \circ f: B \to A$ will be one to one and that will finish the proof

Comment: Yes, $h=g\circ f$ is the function that finishes the proof. I am not sure what your $X$ is, but if you are referring to the set $X_{(a,b)}$ I defined, that set is actually only used to define $f$.